# Can't resolve dependencies from Artifactoryonline

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have a problem with dependancies. Here is my pom file.

https://github.com/Krasnyanskiy/artifactory-test-project/blob/master/pom.xml

And here is dependancy on **Artifactoryonline**.

http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/webapp/browserepo.html?3&pathId=jrs-ce-releases:com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/jasperserver-dto/maven-metadata.xml

I can't see dependancy in my project. Actually Maven doesn't see it.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperserver-dto</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any ideas why it happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The artifactory-test-project build fails due to a missing dependency:

```
Could not find artifact com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:server:pom:5.6.0
```

This artifact is declared as the parent of jasperserver-dto:

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>jasperserver-dto</artifactId>
```

Version 5.6.0 of this artifact is indeed missing from http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jrs-ce-releases
The 5.6.0-SNAPSHOT version of this artifact is available in http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jrs-ce-snapshots

Comment: 5.6.0 is available in release, issue does not reproduce for me: http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jrs-ce-releases/com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/jasperserver-dto/5.6.0/

Comment: @MrsTang The missing release dependency is com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:server:pom:5.6.0

Comment: dependencies are now deployed, issue is confirmed gone. Thanks again, @drorb